# react use-states are not updating, in stack navigator header right component. react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

react use-states are not updating, in stack navigator header right component. react navigation

Example:

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const stackRef = navigation;
    stackRef.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <SubmitButton />,
    });
  }, []);

  const SubmitButton = () => {
    return (
      <Text>count: {count}</Text> // <--- count is not updating and the value is 0
    );
  };

  return(
    <Button onPress={()=>{setCount(count+1)} />
  )
```

Comment: Did you try to console log on the onpress of button to ensure that the onpress function is indeed being called and the state is being updated?

Comment: yes i have tested it using console.log

Comment: Try passing count as a prop to submit button component instead of directly using it from state